# show every result of foreach loop

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview, foreach

I made a `<List>DateTime` class which named GetDataRange so that users can get days between two specific days.

Then I want to show days in the columns of data grid view. I use a foreach loop, This loop will cause a problem. The problem is it won't show all days in the columns because I want to show all days in other calendar. see the codes :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtEnd.Subtract(dtStart).Days; i++)
        {
            TimeSpan counter = new TimeSpan(i, 0, 0, 0);

            string s1 = "10/9/2012";
            string s2 = "11/10/2012";
            d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(s1);
            d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(s2);

            foreach (DateTime item in GetDateRange(d1, d2))
            {
                s = item.ToShortDateString();
            }


            PersianCalendar p = new PersianCalendar();
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(s);
            int day = p.GetDayOfMonth(date);
            int month = p.GetMonth(date);
            int year = p.GetYear(date);
            string dt = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", year, month, day);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(string.Format("col{0}", i), string.Format("{0} {1}", (dtStart + counter).DayOfWeek.ToString(), dt));


        }
```

It will show only one day because of that foreach loop. DayOfWeek is working perfectly but the problem is showing the days in foreach loop it will only show one day.

**UPDATE**

string dt only show one day it won't show other days.

Comment: You haven't shown what `GetDateRange` does but the inner loop makes not much sense since you're always overriding the value: `foreach (DateTime item in GetDateRange(d1, d2))
            {
                s = item.ToShortDateString();
            }
`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter how can i show all of them? because i want to show every of them to another calendar

Comment: I must admit that i don't understand what you're doing here. But if you loop anything you should not just override a value in that loop but use the variable directly. I don't understand also why you convert `s` which is a `DateTime` via `ToShortDateString` to a `string` and two lines later you're converting it back to a `DateTime`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter s is a public string

Comment: @TimSchmelter it don't override the value. I use foreach loop the get all days between two days. and i transfer the values to a public string which named s. then i want to convert s to another calendar then add this to the datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. because every time in the loop you are overriding the value. can you show the dates in a new row.

Try this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtEnd.Subtract(dtStart).Days; i++)
        {
            TimeSpan counter = new TimeSpan(i, 0, 0, 0);                                       
           dataGridView1.Columns.Add(string.Format("col{0}", i), string.Format("{0}", (dtStart + counter).DayOfWeek.ToString()));
        }
```

Then add new row for that :

```
 d1 = dtStart;
        d2 = dtEnd;
        foreach (DateTime item in GetDateRange(d1, d2))
        {
            int day = p.GetDayOfMonth(item);
            int month = p.GetMonth(item);
            int year = p.GetYear(item);
            string dt1 = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", year, month, day);
            listBox1.Items.Add(dt1);

        }
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value = listBox1.Items[i];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

        }
```